# Adding 2x2 PNG Subfigures, natwidth, natheight

Tags: graphics, subfloats, png

How do I add 2x2 PNG figures using subfigures? I am unsure as to how the natural height/width (natwidth, natheight) mean and there is a huge gap in between the figures.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fleqn}
\usepackage{amsmath} %%I am adding this!
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}\hfill
                    \includegraphics[width=2\textwidth,natwidth=610,natheight=642]    {![https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LWRc.png][1]}
                \caption{x}
  \label{fig:First_figure}
     %           \label{fig:gull}
       \end{subfigure}%
           ~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad etc.
      %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=2\textwidth,natwidth=610,natheight=642]{![https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ICcj.png][2]}
            \caption{x}      \label{sf:Second_Figure}
    \end{subfigure}\\        
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}%
            \includegraphics[width=2\textwidth,natwidth=610,natheight=642]{![ https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBLCq.png][3]}
            \caption{x}
            \label{fig:Third_Figure}
                   \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=2\textwidth,natwidth=610,natheight=642]{![https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8lB6.png][4]}
            \caption{x}
            \label{fig:Forth_Figure}
                   \end{subfigure}
                  \caption{bla}
            \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: don't set natheight and natwidth at all and width=2\textwidth makes the figure twice as wide as the page, you probably want .4 not 2

Comment: You have ` ~ %add desired spacing between images, e.` and have  put `~ \hfill` there but  as you have made both the subfigures .5\textwidth so there can be no gap between them.

Comment: PNG images have to have a defined size using \natwidth\natheight otherwise undefined size errors arise.

Comment: are you using pdflatex? You should not get that error in that case.

Comment: I converted all my images to .eps and made it work with just latex. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{amssymb}
% no!\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% remove in real case
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fleqn}
\usepackage{amsmath} %%I am adding this!
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}\centering%no!\hfill
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a}
                \caption{w}
  \label{fig:First_figure}
       \end{subfigure}%
%no, don't use ~!           ~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad etc.
      %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
    \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}\centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{b}
                \caption{x}
  \label{fig:Second_figure}
       \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}\centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{c}
                \caption{y}
  \label{fig:Third_figure}
       \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}\centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{d}
                \caption{z}
  \label{fig:First_figure}
       \end{subfigure}%

\caption{4 figures}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @david-carlisle it was givnig error "latex missing number treated as zero" at line \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}.

Comment: @bvbdort  the above code runs without error (in texlive 2014 and 2015), check you have copied it correctly.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for reply. I am using it in texmaker and error was present.

Comment: @bvbdort sorry can't guess (texmaker though is just the editor, presumably any error you got was from the underlying tex system) maybe you have an old version of some package, I really don't know.